# How to match a sequence of complex patterns?

Tags: pattern-matching

I have list with the form `{{a1,b1}->{x1,y1},{a2,b2}->{x1,y2},...}` where the `{ai,bi}`'s can be `{}`. I know the elements of the list can be matched by `{___} -> {_, _}`, but I don't know how to match a list of this form. So how can I match it?

**UPDATE**: I meant a pattern test: To test whether a list is in this form

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We needn't use `Map` and `Apply` as in ziyuang's answer. We can make use of `PatternSequence` with `Repeated` `(..)` or `RepeatedNull` `(...)` instead, e.g.

```
list = {{a1, b1} -> {x1, y1}, {} -> {x3, y3}, {a2, b2} -> {x1, y2}, 
        {} -> {x6, y6}, {} -> {x5, y5}, {} -> {x0, y0}, {a3, b3} -> {x3, y3}, 
        {a4, b4} -> {x4, y4}};
```

Now we can test various approaches :

```
{ MatchQ[ #, { PatternSequence[{___} -> {_, _}] ..}]& @ list, 
  MatchQ[ #, {({PatternSequence[]} | {_, _} -> {_, _}) ..}]& @ list,
  MatchQ[ #, {({PatternSequence[___]} -> {_, _}) ..}]& @ list }
```

> ```
> {True, True, True}
> ```

The advantage of `PatternSequence` is seen when we'd like to deal with more sophisticated cases of pattern matching.

Comment: I think `PatternSequence[{___} -> {_, _}]` can be substituted by `({___} -> {_, _})`

Comment: @ziyuang What did you mean ?  Try `MatchQ[#, ({___} -> {_, _})] &@ list` and you should get `False`.

Comment: `({___} -> {_, _})..`, of course.

Comment: @ziyuang With `PatternSequence` you can match a broad range of sequences, intermediate ones with respect to very general `x__` and very specific `x..`.

Answer (score 7):

The pattern to match a list of zero or more such terms is

```
List[({___}->{_,_})...]
```

If you want to only match if there's at least one entry in the list, use one dot less:

```
List[({___}->{_,_})..]
```

So to test that `list` has that form, use (assuming an empty list is allowed)

```
MatchQ[list, List[({___}->{_,_})...]]
```

and to define a function accepting only such lists, write

```
f[x:List[({___}->{_,_})...]] := somethingUsing[x]
```

Comment: Though I choose @Artes 's reply as the answer, yours is also very helpful, Thank you~

Answer (score 4):

I've found it myself. Use `And@@(MatchQ[#,{___} -> {_, _}]&/@theList)`

Answer (score 2):

```
{{a1, b1} -> {x1, y1}, {a2, b2} -> {x1, y2}} /.  HoldPattern[{___} -> {_, _}] -> "your match"
```

Comment: I meant a pattern test.